# How to dynamically add formatted ticks?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a bubble chart that I'm trying to add formatted ticks to. I also have the array that contains the strings I want to replace the numbered ticks with. An example of how my array will look like is this: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]. This array will vary in length and values on run time, but it will still contain strings. Preformatted ticks will range from 1 - length of array. 1 will be replaced with "A", 2 will be replaced with "B" and so forth. Because the array is only known during run time, I cannot do this:

```
hAxis: {
  ticks: [
    {v: 1, f: 'A'},
    {v: 2, f: 'B'},
    {v: 3, f: 'C'},
    {v: 4, f: 'D'}
  ]
},
```

How can I output the ticks in the correct format? I've tried using a for-loop to mimic the style of the ticks format, but I am not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var input = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

var ticks = input.map(function(item, index) {
  return { v: index + 1, f: item };
});

console.log(ticks);
```